# Whats the correct way to copy multiple C-Style arrays into one larger array?

Tags: c++, arrays

so i've been trying to figure out what i'm doing wrong in this piece of code but without any luck.

basically i have a `Vertex` struct which contains three elements, two of them which are `vec3`s and one `vec2` and a `Data()` function that returns a C-Style float array/pointer (`float*`).

```
struct Vertex
{
    vec3 Position;
    vec3 Normal;
    vec2 UV;

    float* Data()
    {
        return new float[8] {
            Position.x, Position.y, Position.z,
            Normal.x, Normal.y, Normal.z,
            UV.x, UV.y
        };
    }
}
```

and a class `Shape` which has a method `void SetVertices(const std::vector<Vertex>& vertices)`

so what i'm trying to achieve is to copy all of the vertices data from the vector to one large array

```
void Shape::SetVertices(const std::vector<Vertex>& vertices)
{
    /* size_t */ m_VerticesSize = vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex);
    /* float* */ m_VerticesData = new float[m_VerticesSize];

    float* data = nullptr;

    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); ++i)
    {
        data = vertices[i].Data();

        memcpy(m_VerticesData + (i * sizeof(Vertex)), data, sizeof(Vertex));

        delete[] data;
    }
}
```

when i try to print the values stored in `m_VerticesData` i get this:

```
0.5
0.5
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
9.31644e-39
0.0
4.62428e-44
0.0
2.47549e+13
3.06114e-41
2.47549e+13
3.06114e-41
2.46317e+13
3.06114e-41
6.86636e-44
0.0
7.14495e+31
2.73451e+20
1.89395e+34
3.05061e+29
2.7953e+20
7.44159e+28
3.45427e+30
3.19366e-09
2.46018e+13
3.06114e-41
4.62428e-44
0.0
```

The first vertex data is correct, but the rest is garbage, so any ideas on what i'm doing wrong here?

on a side note, i have to use a C-Style array here in order to create an opengl vertex buffer out of it, so i can't use `std::array` or `std::vector` in this case.

Comment: "..so i can't use std::array or std::vector in this case." not sure about that. `std::array` and `std::vector` have `data()` that grants you access to the underlying c-array

Comment: Yeah i do know that, but in this case ```data()``` would return an array of ```Vertex``` objects, which is not what i'm trying to achieve, i want the data that is stored in those ```Vertex``` objects

Comment: @IshoAntar what do you mean? I still don't see why you would think that you can't use the standard containers.

Comment: @eerorika [glBufferData](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml) needs a parameter of type ```float*``` in order to generate a buffer so i can't pass an array of type ```Vertex*``` to it.

Comment: @IshoAntar But you can pass a pointer to an element in an array of type `Vertex`.

Comment: OK, that worked, i feel really dumb for not thinking about this from the beginning, i've been trying to do this for like an hour now, Thanks a lot :)

Comment: VLAs are not part of C++ and depends on compiler extensions. Just FYI but it's a common portability issue and so creates technical debt.

Comment: @doug Where have you seen a VLA? Might have overlooked, but I only see dynamically allocated arrays...

Comment: @Aconcagua My error. Jumped to conclusion from the question which mentioned C style arrays but they are only dynamic.